# Highlight sentence based on word count

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote VBA code to iterate through each sentence of a document, highlight it based on its word count, and record a tally.

At the end, I get a pop up window that tells me how many sentences are within each word count bucket. It's similar to what I saw on Hemmingway but I want to see the mix of sentences in a doc, not grammar stuff or anything.

Instead of highlighting the sentence and ending at the appropriate punctuation, it highlights the whole background cell (to borrow an Excel term).

```vb
Sub Total_Highlighter()

    Dim iCountA As Integer
    Dim iCountB As Integer
    Dim iCountC As Integer
    Dim iCountD As Integer
    Dim iCountE As Integer
    Dim iCountF As Integer

    'Saves your doc
    If Not ActiveDocument.Saved Then
        ActiveDocument.Save
    End If

    'Reset counter
    iMyCountA = 0
    iMyCountB = 0
    iMyCountC = 0
    iMyCountD = 0
    iMyCountE = 0
    iMyCountF = 0

    For Each MySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences

        If MySent.Words.Count = 0 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
        
        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 6 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(217, 151, 149)
            iMyCountA = iMyCountA + 1
        
        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 11 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(250, 192, 144)
            iMyCountB = iMyCountB + 1

        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 16 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(194, 214, 154)
            iMyCountC = iMyCountC + 1

        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 21 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(184, 204, 228)
            iMyCountD = iMyCountD + 1

        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 31 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(141, 180, 227)
            iMyCountE = iMyCountE + 1

        ElseIf MySent.Words.Count < 41 Then
            MySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = RGB(178, 161, 199)
            iMyCountF = iMyCountF + 1

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox iMyCountA & " sentences shorter than or equal to 5 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iMyCountB & " sentences shorter than or equal to 10 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iMyCountC & " sentences shorter than or equal to 15 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iMyCountD & " sentences shorter than or equal to 20 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iMyCountE & " sentences shorter than or equal to 30 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iMyCountF & " sentences shorter than or equal to 40 words." & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

The only highlight function that worked was `Shading.ForegroundPatternColor`.

I also tried:

`Shading.BackgroundPatternColor` (yielded the same result as above)

`Range.HighlightColorIndex` (received a 438 error)

`Replacement.Highlight` (received a 438 error)

Answer (score 0):

You code is close to finish.

- Added code to remove the paragraph marker from the last sentence
- `Option Explicit` is useful to avoid coding error. eg. `Dim iCountA As Integer` but a different variable is used in `iMyCountA = iMyCountA + 1`. You will get a compiler error if there is `Option Explicit` in your code.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim iCountA As Long， iCountB As Long， iCountC As Long
    Dim iCountD As Long, iCountE As Long, iCountF As Long
    Dim iColor As Long, iCount As Long
    Dim mySent As Range
    'Saves your doc
    If Not ActiveDocument.Saved Then
        ActiveDocument.Save
    End If
    'Reset counter
    iCountA = 0
    iCountB = 0
    iCountC = 0
    iCountD = 0
    iCountE = 0
    iCountF = 0
    For Each mySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences
        ' Remove the paragraph marker from the last sentence
        If mySent.Paragraphs(1).Range.End = mySent.End Then
            mySent.End = mySent.End - 1
        End If
        iColor = 0
        iCount = mySent.Words.Count
        If iCount = 0 Then
            iColor = wdColorWhite
        ElseIf iCount < 6 Then
            iColor = RGB(217, 151, 149)
            iCountA = iCountA + 1
        ElseIf iCount < 11 Then
            iColor = RGB(250, 192, 144)
            iCountB = iCountB + 1
        ElseIf iCount < 16 Then
            iColor = RGB(194, 214, 154)
            iCountC = iCountC + 1
        ElseIf iCount < 21 Then
            iColor = RGB(184, 204, 228)
            iCountD = iCountD + 1
        ElseIf iCount < 31 Then
            iColor = RGB(141, 180, 227)
            iCountE = iCountE + 1
        ElseIf iCount < 41 Then
            iColor = RGB(178, 161, 199)
            iCountF = iCountF + 1
        End If
        If iColor > 0 Then mySent.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = iColor
    Next
    MsgBox iCountA & " sentences shorter than or equal to 5 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iCountB & " sentences shorter than or equal to 10 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iCountC & " sentences shorter than or equal to 15 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iCountD & " sentences shorter than or equal to 20 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iCountE & " sentences shorter than or equal to 30 words." & vbCrLf & _
      iCountF & " sentences shorter than or equal to 40 words." & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a much cleaner If-Then-Else statement! Thank you as well for catching the instance issue I completely was blind to it and am surprised that didn't cause an error!